# Cordova and Back4app: Not getting Push notification on Android

Tags: cordova, push-notification, back4app

I m using cordova to make a hybrid application. The back4app push notification works well on iOS devices but not working in Android. I have checked followings

1. Android device is getting registered in back4app
2. GCM Sender ID and API key is correctly set.

When I send push notification from back4app dashboard, the device doesnot get notification. When I see past pushes in dashboard, the status of push sent is 0

**UPDATE** : `deviceToken` is also missing as well. But when i checked app on Android Oreo, `deviceToken` is registered in back4app and could get push as well.

Am I missing anything? I m new to back4app.

Thanks

Comment: Hey! Is the device token being saved on Back4App Dashboard?

Comment: Hi! I recommend you to contact them in order to check if there's anything being missed on the android push notification settings. (:

Comment: @nataliec Device Token is missing For Android Pie devices. Push working on Oreo, but not on Pie

Comment: Which SDK version are you using with the Pie devices? @WatsMyName

Comment: As Charles said, I also recommend you to contact Back4App support team to check more details about it.